# How to navigate up a folder in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I move up one directory in VS Code explorer? There seems to be no file named `..` and therefore no way to navigate to the parent directory. I don't understand.

Comment: Amazingly, the parent directory `..` is still not shown in 2022... (Version 1.66 on macOS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way is use the navigation explorer and click on the folder you want to go.
I did a searching in keyboard shortcuts but there are nothing related to "folder navigation" we can use.

Comment: As Osram noted, the file options from the menu offer many options to choose your starting directory.  Also, using the command line offering 'code' will let you choose your starting directory.

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu v18 VS CODE you can use Menu: File ► Open Folder
Shortcuts [Ctrl K / Ctrl O]

Comment: funny that it restarted my electron app as I changed the directory

Answer (score 2):

That bothered me a bit as well, but I realized if I start out at a high enough level, I have access to everything.

Comment: Works with a space between cd and .. i.e. **cd ..**

Comment: This doesn't work if you don't choose a high enough level the first time, because even if you close the connection and then connect again, VSCode drops you back at the old location.  The only thing that worked for me was uninstalling the relevant extensions and then re-installing.